# Why is jupyter notebook a web server?

Tags: python, webserver

I just installed Jupiter Notebook. I was expecting a normal program on my computer but somehow it is a web server that I run on my local machine (maybe I got that wrong). I was wondering why this choice was made and what are the advantages.

Comment: Jupyter notebook is an HTML page.  That makes the choice of web server a natural.

Comment: This allows it to work without requiring you to install another webserver, it's all self-contained.

Comment: By the way, there is also now a JupyterLab Desktop App available, see [here](https://blog.jupyter.org/jupyterlab-desktop-app-now-available-b8b661b17e9a). You may though want to stick with what you already have installed now as not everything is available in the desktop app that you'll see described for JupyterLab.